# Web Service Request in HTTPS is directed to clientaccesspolicy in the middle of the session as HTTP

Tags: wcf, https, silverlight-5.0, clientaccesspolicy.xml

I am working on a Silverlight 5 application which is able to get data using wcf web services. But once a save or delete is attempted the clientaccesspolicy.xml file is requested. This request happens in the HTTP protocol which the browser then reports `Display mixed content` javascript popup dialog. The asynchronous call done such as `BeginSaveChanges` silently fails, does not get an error message back in the callback. Why is the app which was working and getting data via HTTPS, happy as a clam suddenly wants the clientaccess policy file and all comes grinding to a halt?

Before the failure Fiddler shows a successful call to the actual webservice to get data. But when the save/delete call is made, an http call to the root clientaccesspolicy gets redirected to the subdomains clientaccesspolicy.xml.

### Fiddler Session Capture

```
#   Result  Protocol    Host    URL Body    Caching Content-Type    Process Comments    Custom  
285 200 HTTPS   test.application.company.com    /SUBSITE/WebService.svc/Terms()?$orderby=Description...{removed}... 742,658 no-cache    application/atom+xml;type=feed;charset=utf-8    iexplore:16376          
286 302 HTTP    test.application.company.com    /clientaccesspolicy.xml 189     text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:16376          
287 200 HTTP    test.application.company.com    /SUBSITE/clientaccesspolicy.xml 341     text/xml    iexplore:16376          
288 302 HTTP    test.application.company.com    /crossdomain.xml    182     text/html; charset=UTF-8    iexplore:16376          
289 200 HTTP    test.application.company.com    /SUBSITE/crossdomain.xml    170     text/xml    iexplore:16376
```

I do not see the actual webserivce call in Fiddler, due to the failure, but I do see it when I run it locally under HTTPS.

### Errata

- The test server I am hitting does have a load balancer in the mix.
- When I debug this on my local machine's IIS it works and I do see the proper delete call go through with no issues with `mixed content all in`https` per Fiddler.
- As noted above the website hosting the control is in a level below the primary (default site) as designated `SUBSITE` above.
- The context is created by passing in a url of `https://test.application.company.com/SUBSITE/WebService.svc` instead of using the default in `ServiceReferences.ClientConfig`.
- Certificate on test server used above is a self signed cert with problems due to not being trusted.
- Both the primary and the hosting site have clientaccesspolicy.xml and crossdomain.xml.

  ```
  <access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
      <!-- Silverlight 3 or higher requires the http-request-headers attribute. -->
      <policy>
        <allow-from http-request-headers="*" https-request-headers="*">
          <domain uri="https://*" />
          <domain uri="http://*" />
        </allow-from>
        <grant-to>
           <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
        </grant-to>
      </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
  </access-policy>
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was within the load balancer. Once the balancer used the SSL certificate to communicate with the webservices the mixed mode page went away.